# How to increase the limit of email you can bulk send on SuiteCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to mail all of my accounts in SuiteCRM.  I have about 80.  I get an error message telling me I can't send to more than 10.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a limit inside SuiteCRM software (maybe on your hosting provider).

If you are facing a limitation it must be due to your STMP provider. (maybe gmail? it has ~100 limit).

What you do have is a per-batch limit configuration (available under admin->Campaign Email Settings) which is normally set to 500 emails per batch.